# Find ancestor attribute with certain descendant attribute using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

This is my xml file:

```html
<Modifications>
  <Modification Name="Acetyl" DeltaMass="42.010565" >
    <ModificationTargets>
      <Target AminoAcid="C" Classification="Post_translational" />
      <Target AminoAcid="H" Classification="Chemical_derivative" />
      <Target AminoAcid="K" Classification="Multiple" />
      <Target AminoAcid="R" Classification="Artefact" />
      <Target AminoAcid="S" Classification="Post_translational" />
      <Target AminoAcid="T" Classification="Post_translational" />
      <Target AminoAcid="Y" Classification="Chemical_derivative" />
    </ModificationTargets>
  </Modification>
  <Modification Name="Amidated" DeltaMass="-0.984016" >
    <ModificationTargets>
      <Target AminoAcid="Cte" Classification="Post_translational" />
    </ModificationTargets>
   </Modification>
<Modifications>
```

**I want to get Modification attribute(@Name)**

**condition is attribute(@Classification="Post_translational")**

this is what AminoAcid belongs to "Post_translational":

`xpathExpression = "//Target[contains(@Classification,'Post_translational')]/@AminoAcid";`

**result: [C, S, T, Cte]**

so i want this result help me to find ancestor attribute(@Name):

`xpathExpression ="//Target[@Classification='Post_translational']/ancestor::Modification/@Name";`

**result: [Acetyl, Amidated]**

but i want individual @Name of each AminoAcid:

**ideal result: [Acetyl, Acetyl, Acetyl, Amidated]**

How can i fix this xpathExpression?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XPath:

```
//Modification[.//Target[contains(@Classification,'Post_translational')]]/@Name
```

Comment: Thank you. But i still got same result  [Acetyl, Amidated].  I think maybe need @AminoAcid this condition together.

Comment: If we can use @AminoAcid it will be good, but it is changing for each element

Comment: Yes, I have been troubled for a long time :(

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems you're running into is that the `/` operator eliminates duplicates - obviously, in your case 3 of the 4 target attribute values are identical and so two are eliminated. To avoid that you can use, if xpath 3.1 is available to you, [the simple map operator which avoids this behavior:](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-map-operator)

```
//Target[@Classification="Post_translational"]!ancestor::Modification/string(@Name)
```

Alternatively, you can use xquery:

```
declare context item := document {
  your xml above
};
for $target in //Target[@Classification="Post_translational"]
return $target/ancestor::Modification/string(@Name)
```

In either case, the output should be:

```
Acetyl
Acetyl
Acetyl
Amidated
```